# Sorting an arraylist of object base on its property in custom order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I need to sort my array list in custom order (not alphabetical order) by its own String property.

```
List<WeekSales> saleList = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

WeekSales:

```
public class WeekSales{

private String day;
private int amount;

// getters setters
...

}
```

Property `day` is always a day of the week. ("Sunday","Monday", etc...) So I need to order the elements of the list according to the order of the week.("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")

So I tried with `google.common.collect.Ordering.` But it gives me an error

> Cannot compare value: com.certus.controllers.WeekSales

```
Comparator<WeekSales> com = Ordering.explicit(new WeekSales("Monday",0), new WeekSales("Tuesday",0), new WeekSales("Wednesday",0), new WeekSales("Thursday",0), new WeekSales("Friday",0), new WeekSales("Saturday",0),new WeekSales("Sunday",0));
                saleList.sort(com);
```

Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

> UPDATE :

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784514/5454585) has no any solution for my problem. I have got a custom order in my case.

```
("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you actually try to sort a list containing the items listed in the parameters of `Ordering.explicit`, it doesn't know how to sort them. It's also not clear if you've overridden your `WeekSales.equals` (and `hashCode`), which would be required for that to work too.

You need to actually tell it the fields to compare:

```
class YourComparator implements Comparator<WeekSales> {
  private final Ordering<String> dayOrdering = Ordering.explicit(
    "Monday", "Tuesday", ... );

  @Override public int compare(WeekSales a, WeekSales b) {
    return dayOrdering.compare(a.getDay(), b.getDay());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a Map to help.

```
Map<String, Integer> dayToOrder= new HashMap<>();
for (String day: "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday".split(","))
    dayToOrder.put(day, dayToOrder.size());
```

To sort your collection

```
List<WeekSales> saleList = new ArrayList<>();

saleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ws -> dayToOrder.get(ws.day)));
```

Another solution is to use an `enum` from the start.

```
enum WeekDay {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday;
}

public class WeekSales {

    private WeekDay day; // can only be a valid week day
    private int amount;

    // getters setters
    WeekDay getDay() { return day; }
    ...

}
```

then to sort you can use the `ordinal()`

```
 saleList.sort(Comparator.comparing(WeekDay::getDay));
```

Comment: I guess you mean `"Monday,etc".split(",")`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou works better not I go the name right. ;)

Comment: With your answer I can perform ordering without any support of external library. Really appreciate about the facts. But with my case it is easy to go with @AndyTurner 's answer without making much changes to the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an enum for your week days:

```
public enum WeekDay {
   MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;
}
```

And then your class would look like this:

```
public class WeekSales implements Comparable<WeekSales>{
    private WeekDay day;
    private int amount;

    //Add a comparison method
    public int compareTo(WeekSales otherWeekSales) {
        return this.day.ordinal() - otherWeekSales.day.ordinal();
    }
}
```

That code implements the comparable interface and the compareTo method uses the order of the WEEKDAY value to compare.

And to sort:

```
Collections.sort(saleList); //That will use the compareTo method implemented in the class.
```

Comment: `enum` are already Comparable, you could do `day.compareTo(otherWeekSales.day)`

Comment: Effective Java 2nd ed Item 31 ("Use instance fields instead of ordinals") suggests that such a use of ordinals is not a good idea, e.g. there is nothing to stop somebody "innocently" changing the order of members in the enum, which changes the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you implement your Comparator in this way:

```
Comparator<WeekSales> com = new Comparator<WeekSales>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(WeekSales o1, WeekSales o2) {
    //do stuff with o1 and o2 by getDay()
    return 0;
    }
};
```